# Default iOS Simulator photos from Xcode 6?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6

Where do these five images come from?

[image: iOS Simulator Screenshot with 5 Default Photos in Photos.app]

They seem to be installed on all iOS simulators when launched via Xcode 6. Even after resetting the simulator they show up.

I ask because I want to depend on these images being there for automated testing but can't track down where they are coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They come from the sample content that is installed when simulators are created or erased.  This content is located in the simruntime bundle.

See `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/SampleContent`